# How to set database name as a variable in SSIS?

Tags: variables, ssis, oledbconnection

In my current project, the database name keeps changing and I do not want to modify my OLE DB Sources each time. Thus I want to set it as a variable. That is, in each OLE DB Source, I could use it as a parameter. However, it seems SSIS doesn't allow database name to be transferred as a parameter. So what should I do to minimize my changes?

I wish to do something like this SQL statement in OLE DB Source:

```
Select OrderID
  From ?.Order
```

And I just need to modify my variable when the database name is changed. 
Thanks for any solutions!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add package configurations to your package and set the database name of the connection manager as one of the configurations

[image]

Just right click any blank area on the control flow and select "package configuration" and follow the wizard.

I Suggest you start with a XML configuration because its easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions for you:

- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/sqlintegrationservices/thread/586bf0a7-16c1-4a24-a9b2-7b8fb0cffda9
- http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/b72e1b45-9a78-4865-912a-4587fa72c7f7

Answer (score 0):

I like to manage Server\Instance.Database at the connection manager and Schema.Table or View at the task or adapter level. I recommend externalizing connection manager connection strings. You can use Package Configurations to do this, or you can manage it yourself (I use a table with ConnectionName and ConnectionString columns, and encrypt the ConnectionString column). In my opinion, a hard-coded database name inside an SSIS package is not a best practice.

I recently recorded a couple sessions on SSIS Connections management - one for [2005, 2008, and 2008 R2](http://andyleonard.me/wp3/managing-ssis-connections/); [another for 2012](http://andyleonard.me/wp3/managing-connections-in-ssis-2012/). I have also recorded a session on [managing configurations in SSIS](http://andyleonard.me/wp3/microtraining-ssis-package-configurations/) (although the audio is poor).

I hope these help.

Andy

Answer (score 0):

Check out this terrific post on how to parameterize the database name.  This a very thorough blog post on the topic of parameters and environments in SSIS.

http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2015/1/4/parameterizing-connections-and-values-at-runtime-using-ssis-environment-variables